# How to reverse a drop-down box

Tags: javascript

I have an ASP.NET page that displays a dropown box. I need to reverse it using javascript. Is this possible and how?

Comment: what do you mean by `reverse`?

Answer (score 0):

```
function fx(e)
{
  for(var i=e.options.length-2;i>=0;i--)
  {
    e.appendChild(e.options[i]);
  }
}
```

The argument e is the select-element that should be reversed.
It's a simple approach, it doesn't handle optgroups.

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/ke9mX/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/ke9mX/)